# How to monitor pexpect buffer for changes

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a device I'm trying to control and make a pexpect wrapper for with many different prompts, some of which can easily be found in other output that isn't a prompt. However; the device is quite fast with output and never has any functions where it's waiting without putting *something* out. So is there a way to monitor the buffer for pexpect and wait until it stops changing, then just return that without using the 'expect' function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using the pexpect method `read_nonblocking(size=,timeout=)` which returns immediately with any data, or raises a timeout exception if the first byte is not found in the time given.  By repeating it in a loop until it times out, and accumulating the data, you will be detecting the end of output, when the device is quiet. Consider the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pexpect

class Myspawn(pexpect.spawn):
    def readall(self):
        data = b""
        while 1:
            try:
                data += self.read_nonblocking(size=999,timeout=1)
            except pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT:
                return data.decode('iso-8859-1')

cmd = '''while read time repeats rest
         do sleep $time; for i in $(seq $repeats);do echo $i $rest; done
         done'''
child = Myspawn('bash',['-c',cmd])

child.sendline(".1 1 test line")
print(child.readall())
child.sendline(".9 10 test line")
print(child.readall())
```

The `readall()` method loops infinitely accumulating the reads (which are bytes, not strings), and when finally there is no more data, the timeout exception causes it to return the data.

For testing, the command being run, `cmd`, is a bash shell script that simply loops waiting for input lines. The line you write to it is split into a wait time `time` and a repeat count `repeats`. It repeats the rest of the line after the wait, which is meant to simulate a burst of output after a small amount of processing delay.

You can experiment with this to verify that provided any pause in the output takes less than the `read_nonblocking()` timeout, the loop will not finish and you will lose no data. Changing the `size=` parameter should have no effect, other than causing more looping. Obviously, you should choose a timeout that is reasonably short, but not too short for commands that do not react quickly.